# SQL Server Lag and Lead

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lag, lead

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].tmpJobStatus
(
    [JobNum] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Action] [VARCHAR](8) NULL,
    [ActionDate] [DATE] NULL,
    [SeqNum] [INT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have some data:

```
INSERT INTO tmpJobStatus ([JobNum], [Action], [ActionDate], [SeqNum]) 
VALUES (12345, N'TEL', CAST(N'2019-07-05' AS Date), 19),
       (12345, N'AL2', CAST(N'2019-07-02' AS Date), 15),
       (12345, N'AL1', CAST(N'2019-05-28' AS Date), 8),
       (12345, N'TELA', CAST(N'2019-05-16' AS Date), 2),
       (6789, N'MAIN', CAST(N'2019-11-04' AS Date), 25),
       (6789, N'MAIN', CAST(N'2019-11-04' AS Date), 21),
       (6789, N'TEL', CAST(N'2019-10-29' AS Date), 20),
       (6789, N'MACO', CAST(N'2019-10-28' AS Date), 13),
       (6789, N'UCIN', CAST(N'2019-09-12' AS Date), 11)
```

If I perform a `LAG` and `LEAD` using the below for one Job, I get the desired result:

```
SELECT
    [JobNum],
    [ActionDate],
    [SeqNum],
    LAG(p.[Action]) OVER (ORDER BY p.[JobNum],p.[SeqNum]) FromActionCode,
    LEAD(p.[Action]) OVER (ORDER BY p.[JobNum],p.[SeqNum]) ToActionCode
FROM 
    [tmpJobStatus] p
WHERE
    [JobNum] = 6789
ORDER BY
    p.[JobNum], p.[SeqNum] DESC
```

Result:

```
JobNum  ActionDate  SeqNum  FromActionCode  ToActionCode
6789    2019-11-04  25    MAIN          NULL
6789    2019-11-04  21    TEL           MAIN
6789    2019-10-29  20    MACO          MAIN
6789    2019-10-28  13    UCIN          TEL
6789    2019-09-12  11    NULL          MACO
```

Notice the NULL for the first FromActionCode and LastToCode, which is correct.

However, If I look at all records, it messes it up:

```
JobNum  ActionDate  SeqNum  FromActionCode  ToActionCode
6789    2019-11-04  25    MAIN              TELA
6789    2019-11-04  21    TEL               MAIN
6789    2019-10-29  20    MACO              MAIN
6789    2019-10-28  13    UCIN              TEL
6789    2019-09-12  11    NULL              MACO
12345   2019-07-05  19    AL2               NULL
12345   2019-07-02  15    AL1               TEL
12345   2019-05-28  8     TELA              AL2
12345   2019-05-16  2     MAIN              AL1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "messes up"? The results look correct to me for what you've specified the SQL to do. What are you expected results? Is it, perhaps, because you're missing a `PARTITION BY` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try with `PARTITION`

```
SELECT [JobNum], [ActionDate], [SeqNum],
       LAG(p.[Action]) OVER (PARTITION BY p.[JobNum] ORDER BY p.[SeqNum]) FromActionCode,
       LEAD(p.[Action]) OVER (PARTITION BY p.[JobNum] ORDER BY p.[SeqNum]) ToActionCode
FROM [tmpJobStatus] p
ORDER BY p.[JobNum],p.[SeqNum] desc
```